# navigator.notification.prompt in PhoneGap works in emulator but not on Android

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to use navigator.notification.prompt to get input from the user and have used the following code which runs and works in the emulator.

I know that the function editInstallQtyPrompt is running as the alert fires and has the id in that I want but the prompt doesn't show

```
function editInstallQtyPrompt() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    projId = id.substring(5);
    alert(projId);
    var value = $(this).text();
    var max = $(this).attr('max');
    navigator.notification.prompt(
            'Please enter a value',
            function(results){onEditInstallQtyPrompt(results, projId, value, max)},
            'Edit install qty',
            ['Ok','Cancel']
    );

}
```

There aren't many instances of this on Stackoverflow that I can see. The ones I have found tend to suggest that there is a problem with my cordova reference but there is only one cordova-2.7.0.js in my build (that I can see) and it is referenced so I am not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked logcat ..

Comment: In the logcat in the emulator there are no errors and it works. Is there a log cat on the tablet I can access ? Where is it ?